# Symfony implementing registration

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony and I am following this tutorial 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

I have copied the code 1:1 with the only difference that my bundle is called UserBundle instead of AccountBundle, respectively my controller is called UserController instead of AccountController. 
Everything seems fine until I reach createAction.

On the line

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints" in property      Acme\UserBundle\Form\Model\Registration::$user does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

The only annotations of  my Registration class are:

```
/**
* @Assert|Type(type='Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User')
* @Assert|Valid()
*/
protected $user;

/**
* @Assert|NotBlank()
 * @Assert|True()
 */
protected $termsAccepted;
```

Exactly as shown in the tutorial.

I am using version 2.3 and I created the project by executing  `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject/ "2.3.*"`

I have all the proper namespaces and I have used all the specified `use` statements in the tutorial. Yet, I am getting this exception. 
What I am missing ? Can you at least tell me what to look for ?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be using pipes - you should use backslashes.

The `@Assert\NotBlank()` annotation is actually referring to the `NotBlank` class in the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints` namespace, which should be in your `use` declarations, like `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert`. This means that the `Assert` part of the annotation is referring to the alias you have assigned to the `Constraints` namespace. Because the annotations are referring to classes, you should be using backslashes to separate the namespaces.

The error indicates that it is trying to load the `Assert` alias directly (so `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints`), which it can't do as there is no class. With the backslash, it will look inside the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints` namespace for the assertion class.

Comment: I can`t believe I did not see that. 
Thanks.